# Signups Forbidden in Accounts UI using Angular Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, angular-meteor

When I click on the login/registration pulldown menus provided by `<login-buttons>` from [`carlosbaraza:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-angular`](https://atmospherejs.com/carlosbaraza/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-angular) package, I am unable to create new accounts, giving the error `Signups forbidden` as shown below.

What may be causing this error and how can we troubleshoot this?

[image]

I'm also using the following packages

```
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
service-configuration

angular-with-blaze
angularui:angular-ui-router
angularutils:pagination
tmeasday:publish-counts
carlosbaraza:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-angular
jasonaibrahim:angular-moment
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-angular-templates   

urigo:angular-blaze-template

twbs:bootstrap
jss:flat-ui
fourseven:scss
fortawesome:fontawesome
useraccounts:core
useraccounts:bootstrap

momentjs:moment
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:delete-button
```

Comment: IMHO looks like config issue, I've checked the native code for the bootstrap and the error comes from `Accounts`

Comment: @maurycy How did you manage to solve the problem? Which config item was causing the problem for you?

Comment: Ahhh, I've seen the list of your packages now, `carlosbaraza:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-angular` doesn't work with other useraccount modules, you will have to remove `useraccounts:bootstrap` and maybe the core (but this I'm not sure so remove the bootstrap first and checkout)

Comment: I had essentially the same problem. For me, I basically resolved it by removing accounts-password, then adding it again.